# "ssh root@server" hangs forever

Tags: ssh, connection

Sometimes my ssh client will take forever to login.

This happens when the server is not responding (overloaded, killed processed, ...). My automated scripts will then fail because the ssh process will never exit.

Is there a ssh configuration value to set a timeout in order to fail if ssh can't login after a predefined number of seconds?

I know there are knobs on the server side, but I have to set this on the client side as the sshd process is not responding, or responding incorrectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've seen cases where even setting ConnectTimeout doesn't work.  This can be particularly annoying when using automated ssh connections to large numbers of servers.  My solution is to use a wrapper on the client side that kills the ssh process if it doesn't connect and return quickly enough.  Something like this (in perl):

```
$SshCmd = "ssh server.example.com uname -a";
$TimeOut = 120;
eval {
  local $SIG{ALRM} =
    sub {
      # ignore SIGHUP here so the kill only affects children.
      local $SIG{HUP} = 'IGNORE';
      kill 1,(-$$);
      print STDERR "ssh terminated, max run time of $TimeOut seconds exceeded.\n";
    };
  alarm $TimeOut;
  system ($SshCmd) || die "failed to run $SshCmd: $!";
  alarm 0;
};
$SIG{HUP} = 'DEFAULT';
```

That sets an alarm of `$TimeOut` seconds, and kills the child (the ssh command) if the alarm is exceeded.

Comment: perl have Net::SSH2, when you set Timeout

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and used the Linux "timeout" to kill a hanging scp session.

```
timeout -s 9 1h command command_arguments
```

Will send a kill -9 if the command takes over an hour.

FYI the ConnectTimeout option did not work for me.

Comment: This is the most thorough option.  `-o ConnectTimeout=x` and `-o BatchMode=yes` will both help, but nothing beats `timeout` for covering 100% of cases, even `ssh` client code failure!


Though you really shouldn't `kill -9` here; there's no need for the `-9`.

Answer (score 3):

Set 'ConnectTimeout' in .ssh/config if use ssh(from OpenSSH).

> **ConnectTimeout**
>
> Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the ssh server, instead of using  he default system TCP timeout. This value is used only when the target is down or really unreachable, not when it refuses the connection.

Try set 'UseDNS no' in sshd_config.

Comment: I'll explain why he recommended this; if your IP has no PTR record it can cause SSH to hang.

Comment: ConnectTimeout doesn't work, generally, after the connection has been established. When I do that in one case, for example, it waits for the  authentication to complete, which can be an indefinite period of time.